# Rules for substituting images with text in question/answer?

Tags: support, images

I just saw an answer's images to this [Minecraft question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8310/whats-the-most-efficient-minecraft-mining-strategy) have been substituted with text ASCII arts.

I like more images in that case than text, but this is a personal opinion. I am wondering instead if I missed something and there was a defined rule to substitute images with text where it was possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no general rule, and I don't think there should be. Stack Exchange has a dedicated account for hosting images, so the main reasons for using one or the other are based on readability. And that depends on the scenario - some answers are easier graphical while others can be done with text.

For the specific question, it's too dark for me to tell what's going on in the image, but I don't play Minecraft, so I'm not going to make a call. Readability might be different to the people who actually play the game.

Answer (score 1):

I made the edit because the image was actually a diagram, and the key to read it was buried in a comment on the second answer. This is not cool. I could've edited the images to add a key to it, but it was less work replacing it altogether with something not as cool looking, but IMHO more easily read.

So, no, there's no rule on this; I merely attempted to improve the answer, [as I always have.](http://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/s/303/top-50-most-prolific-editors)

Comment: You don't need to defend, I voted for you too. It was only a question, no accusation. As I said I prefer the image, in that context was more clear for me, but is a personal opinion.

Comment: @Drake No worries. Thanks for your support.

Comment: It took me a while to figure out what on earth I was looking at when tzenes originally added the image in the first place.  And it was my answer.